How to unfreeze the audio menu in Windows 11 without restarting the computer?
One of the common issues that I've seen on multiple machines in both Windows 10 and Windows 11 is that when an audio device is disconnected, or when an application tries to change Bluetooth mode between "Headphones" and "Headset", the menu for sound in the task bar becomes inaccessible. Sometimes this resolves by restart, sometimes reconnecting the device is enough.
My question here is which service manages this icon/menu on Windows 11, where reconnecting the device does not seem to fix this. To be clear, this icon:

It does not do anything when clicked after disconnecting bluetooth device. I am expecting a service found in services.msc that, if restarted, should make it work again.

Possibly restart Windows Explorer from the task manager.

Or try Ctrl-Alt-Delete to log out, then log in again. It's not as fast as restarting Explorer,  but still far faster than rebooting (about 30 sec to re-login, and ~7minutes for full reboot on this Win 10 PC).

To add to @DrMoishePippik a log out will not restart device drivers, and if a device driver crashed that causes explorer to also hang, neither restarting exlorer nor logging out will fix it, and a reboot is required. If it happens often, check if you can update the audio drivers.
